# WPF - Label text from collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have some label text that I'm trying to generate based on the sum of values within an ObservableCollection.  Essentially, the items in the ObservableCollection each contain a Quantity and PricePerItem property and as I add and remove items from the collection, I'd like the label to update.

Any ideas on how I would get started on this?

Comment: Will you be editing your Employee instances, as well, or just adding/removing employees?

Comment: There is the potential for individual items within the collection to be edited as well as added/removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a bit more difficult than you'd expect.  You can use an `IValueConverter`, but the sum won't stay up to date as you change values within the collection, as the converter doesn't see the change in individual members, only the collection itself.

I wrote a sample for the Expression Code Gallery demonstrating a [Collection Aggregator](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/CollectionAggregator) for WPF which uses a Blend SDK Behavior to do this.  It allows you to display the sum, average, min, max, etc for values within a collection, and have it automatically stay up to date (provided the collection implements `IBindingList` or `INotifyCollectionChanged`, and the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

This works by actually subscribing to the collection changed events, as well as individual elements property changed events, and handling the aggregation for you.

Comment: Since individual items apparently can be edited your solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and bind to the collection.

e.g. a basic sum converter can look like this:

```
public class SumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = value as ObservableCollection<Employee>;
        return (from emp in input
                select emp.Id).Sum();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

If you want to improve reusability you could use the ConverterParameter to pass the property-name that should be summed up and then do so using reflection.

The problem is you need to bind to a collection property, otherwise the collection changed notifications will not update the binding.

Comment: This doesn't work, though, as a change in an individual Employee will not trigger the value converter... See my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I am aware of that, the OP only stated: "as I add and remove items from the collection, I'd like the label to update"